# CAN bus using AT90can

Tags: avr, can-bus

Is there a step by step guide about how to use CAN bus with AT90can32/64/128 microcontrollers. I am not able to find a good resource which start from the basics and explain the total implementation including hardware.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ATMEL did a good job as usual with the [AT90canXX](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc7679.pdf) datasheet, everything you need is there. If you are completely unfamiliar with the *CAN* protocol, take some time to read the [specifications](http://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf).  There is even an official [library page](http://www.atmel.com/tools/cansoftwarelibrary.aspx) (not free, but, hey, lazy men gonna pay for their laziness).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance I will look into these resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmel has a canlib.c and .h hidden away on their site. I got it running on our AT90can32 boards. Olimex sells an AT90can128 bd with schematic and sw on their site.